# 2014 Mac mini on 2 monitors no screen extension option available. Just mirror and regular left right views. Can this be done and how?

Tags: mac-mini, fullscreen

I have 2 monitors on my late 2014 Mac mini with Big Sur latest version but no option of screen extension, just mirror and regular left and right set up. I wonder if this can be done. I need to have this panoramic view of my desktop for my everyday's work. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are defining 'extension' separately to 'regular left & right'. What is it you actually trying to achieve? I see you've tagged this *fullscreen* but if you're after a method to stretch fullscreen over two displays, that can't be done natively. You can drag a window over both screens, but you can't do it as fullscreen, only as in effect 'maximised'.

Comment: Yes, that is what I need to do, have the same screen over the two monitors, like a long spreadsheet. It's got to be a way. After 35 years I switched from pc to Apple and I can't believe I can't do this like before. But it's got to be a way other than me selling the 2014 unit and buying the 2018. 

Comment: But thank you very much for answering. Let's hope someone knows the answer because I think I am not the first person trying to do this.

Comment: It doesn't matter which Mac or which screens you use. You cannot fullscreen or maximise to 2 monitors… but as I already said, you can drag to cover both. Example using this page… https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wc28.jpg

Comment: It is too small I can not read.

Comment: The intention wasn't so you could read it, the intention was to show a single window spanning two screens.

Comment: But this is exactly my problem, it does not let me do this. Maybe I should look  somewhere in settings?

Comment: System Prefs > Mission Control > switch off "Displays have separate Spaces". (I really don't know why people ever switch that on;)

Comment: You don't know how much I appreciate your help, I will try it as soon as I get home. Like I said this is my first Apple and so many things are different from pc.

Comment: It works. And I would like to ask you one more question please, what can I do before turning the Mac off to have that same screen in the same location when I turn the computer back on. Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything.